# Magento2 css images deploy static files language

Tags: magento2, css, production-mode

I'm trying to customize a theme with a child theme. When I add a new class in the css with background image it works like a charm in **development** both EN and FR (my 2 languages). I use the `setup:static-content:deploy` command in my **production** site to apply changes :

- EN : ok
- FR : images don't show in frontend

After many try, I check the **/pub/static** files : images are copied only in the EN folder (/pub/static/frontend/Vendor/theme/en_US/images). If I put directly the image in the fr_FR folder it works.

I'm probably missing something in my .phtml file to declare this in all languages available. Thanks for your help

Comment: Which Magento 2 version do you run?

Comment: Another question, what errors do you get in Chrome developer tools? 404s on the specific images - if so, the second reply in the answer below could be applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've faced two bugs that may be related. This is not really related to your hypothesis about missing something in the .phtml-file.

**Static files are not generated for empty child themes.  There must be one file in the web-folder.** Workaround in short, put one file in the theme/web/images-directory and rerun setup:static-content:deploy.

Read more about it [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/115776/static-content-deploy-not-working-for-custom-theme), or at [GitHub](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3754).

**Bugs in static content deploy**. This bug impacted CSS and language for translated sites for me. I deployed my second language first, and then a global language deploy, on the specified theme. Not in the same command.

Example:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=Magento/luma en_US
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=Magento/luma nl_NL
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme=Magento/luma fr_FR
```

Read more about it [here at GitHub](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7862).

Comment: very interesting reading. that's probably why some of the terms in my child theme where not translated...

Answer (score 2):

Try :

php -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR